# Number of Votes Shown

Tags: support

I was looking for the number of votes I have been casting on the site recently. I though voted couple of times today but my name is not show. Then thinking I might have forgotten to vote I checked some of the recent Q&A to see that I have indeed voted. I voted a few more times and came to the page but still my votes are not shown.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 4):

You don't show up on that page because you only voted 4 time this week, for a user to show up on the week page, he/she has to have voted > 10 times in a week.  If a user has voted > 10 times, and hasn't shown up on the page, then this could be a cache issue.

If you go to your [personal profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/295/suminda-sirinath-salpitikorala) you can scroll to the bottom and look at "Votes Cast" and can accurately tell you how many votes you have given.

Comment: Is this rolling stats or calender stats?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala I think they're stats for this calendar week, where "week" is defined as starting on a Sunday and probably using UTC timezone.